# How to Retrieve the List of Access Points on iOS and Android using a Flutter App

Tags: android, ios, flutter, wifi

I'm looking for a way to retrieve the list of available Access Points in my area using a Flutter app on both iOS and Android devices. Does anyone have experience with this or know how to do it? Any suggestions or guides would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can't do it on iOS, regardless of development language

Comment: and how on android